# I can't recive emails and all outgoing emails go to spam folder

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, spf, hosting

I recently bought a VPS server at OVH.com to host the web of one of our business and I'm having problems  to correctly configure the DNS to be able to send and recive emails.

Right now i can't send emails and the outgoing emails go to Spam folder of Outlook and Gmail, I suspect it has something to do with SPF entry of my DNS settings.

Currently my VPS uses CentOS with Plesk and postfix mail server and OVH manages the DNS through the OVH control panel but i don't know why my mail server is redirected to redirect.ovh.net ( [Pingability Mail Server Info](http://pingability.com/zoneinfo.jsp?domain=bpimmoserveis.com) )

> DNS Settings from my OVH Control Panel: 
>   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51426489/DNS/dns1.PNG

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not spf unless you set `-all`.

The first problem I see is your reverse dns records:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
63.165.222.92.in-addr.arpa. 21599 IN    PTR 63.ip-92-222-165.eu.
```

This should not point to `63.ip-92-222-165.eu`, it should point to your helo string which currently is `vps122779.ovh.net`.

You might wanna change that as well, to mx.bpimmoserveis.com or mail.bpimmoserveis.com

The rule of thumb is that an mx DNS query of your domain should return a host name, if I connect to that host name it should greet me with that same name, and if I do a PTR query on the address it should return that same host name. This does not always apply, but for small setups it's the easiest path to happiness.

For your case we get this:

```
$ dig +noall +answer bpimmoserveis.com mx
bpimmoserveis.com.  3471    IN  MX  1 redirect.ovh.net.
$ dig +noall +answer redirect.ovh.net
redirect.ovh.net.   12846   IN  A   213.186.33.5
```

Strike 1. Also, the MX record on your screen cap has an extra 1, and you usually want your mx record to be a CNAME (i.e., pointing to another hostname, not to an IP address).

```
$ dig +noall +answer -x 92.222.165.63
63.165.222.92.in-addr.arpa. 20847 IN    PTR 63.ip-92-222-165.eu.
```

Strike 2.

```
$ telnet mail.bpimmoserveis.com 25
Trying 92.222.165.63...
Connected to bpimmoserveis.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 vps122779.ovh.net ESMTP Postfix
helo mail.example.org
250 vps122779.ovh.net
^]q
```

Strike 3.

Getting mail right nowadays [is difficult](http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/). You should check allaboutspam.com for guidelines. You can also send an e-mail to test@allaboutspam.com and they'll bounce you a link to a nice report about everything wrong with your setup. Of course, you must be able to receive email first, so fix your mx record and wait for the changes to propagate.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you having and SPF record configured for your domain, at least not one reported by your DNS servers.  This could be your first issue.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -t any bpimmoserveis.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22562
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;bpimmoserveis.com.     IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  SOA dns200.anycast.me. tech.ovh.net. 2014122205 86400 3600 3600000 300
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  NS  dns200.anycast.me.
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  NS  ns200.anycast.me.
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  MX  1 redirect.ovh.net.
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  A   92.222.165.63
bpimmoserveis.com.  3599    IN  TXT "1|www.bpimmoserveis.com"
```

An SPF record should be formed like:

```
microsoft.com.      754 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf-a.microsoft.com include:_spf-b.microsoft.com include:_spf-c.microsoft.com include:_spf-ssg-a.microsoft.com include:spf-a.hotmail.com ip4:147.243.128.24 ip4:147.243.128.26 ip4:147.243.128.25 ip4:147.243.1.47 ip4:147.243.1.48 -all"
```

I concur about checking out the allaboutspam.com site or any site that talks about setting up Sender Policy Framework.